# How to access a web interface on my NAS backup unit which is on our server's internal network

Tags: linux, networking

I hope anyone can help me with this

The setup:
We have a few hosting servers. There are webpages of our clients. We also have a backup unit with web-based control interface. The backup unit is not on public IP. It's hidden in intranet - all our servers and the backup unit are connected together in an internal 10.0.0.0 network.

My question is: How can I access the web interface on the bakcup unit from internet?

Scheme: Internet -> (public IP) -> Server -> (intranet 10.0.0.0) Backup unit

All servers are running Debian if that's any help. I can't just forward port 80 because servers are running webpages. How to do this?

Many thanks!

Comment: No option to VPN into the internal network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are happy having the NAS unit directly accessible from the internet (not recommended) then you can forward any other port on the webservers to port 80 on the NAS (e.g. port 81 on the server => port 80 on the NAS). See:

https://serverfault.com/questions/532569/how-to-do-port-forwarding-redirecting-on-debian

Alternatively a more secure method is to use SSH port forwarding on a client PC. How you do this depends on whether you are using a Windows or Linux client machine. On a Linux client:

ssh -L 80:(nas-unit-intranet-IP):80 username@webserver

On Windows, for example in PuTTY, under Connection => SSH => Tunnels set source port 80, destination (nas-unit-intranet-IP):80, and click Add.

Comment: This should help me! Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may try to proxy all requests on your webserver, for example, on nginx:

```
location /myNAS/ {
    proxy_pass http://nas-address/;
}
```

With that, you can do all sort of authentication and authorization your webserver supports.